# Is it possible to pass a parameter to XSLT through a URL when using a browser to transform XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, browser, transform, param

When using a browser to transform XML (Google Chrome or IE7) is it possible to pass a parameter to the XSLT stylesheet through the URL?

example:

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
<root>
    <document type="resume">
        <author>John Doe</author>
    </document>
    <document type="novella">
        <author>Jane Doe</author>
    </document>
</root>
```

**sample.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="doctype" />
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>List of <xsl:value-of select="$doctype" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="//document[@type = $doctype]">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="author" /></p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</<xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the XSLT server-side, even if the transformation is client-side.

This allows you to use a dynamic script to handle the parameter.

For example, you might specify:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"href="/myscript.cfm/sample.xsl?paramter=something" ?>
```

And then in myscript.cfm you would output the XSL file, but with dynamic script handling the query string parameter (this would vary depending on which scripting language you use).

Comment: Part two of the question would be is it possible client-side only?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, no - you can't pass through parameters to the XSLT on the client-side only.
The web-browser takes the processing instructions from the XML; and directly transforms it with the XSLT.

---

It is possible to pass values via the querystring URL and then read them dynamically using JavaScript. However these wouldn't be available to use in the XSLT (XPath expressions) - as the browser has already transformed the XML/XSLT.  They could only be used in the rendered HTML output.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the parameter as an attribute to the XML source file and use it as an attibute with the stylesheet.

```js
xmlDoc.documentElement.setAttribute("myparam",getParameter("myparam"))
```

And the JavaScript function is as follows:

```js
//Get querystring request paramter in javascript
function getParameter (parameterName ) {

   var queryString = window.top.location.search.substring(1);

   // Add "=" to the parameter name (i.e. parameterName=value)
   var parameterName = parameterName + "=";
   if ( queryString.length > 0 ) {
      // Find the beginning of the string
      begin = queryString.indexOf ( parameterName );
      // If the parameter name is not found, skip it, otherwise return the value
      if ( begin != -1 ) {
         // Add the length (integer) to the beginning
         begin += parameterName.length;
         // Multiple parameters are separated by the "&" sign
         end = queryString.indexOf ( "&" , begin );
      if ( end == -1 ) {
         end = queryString.length
      }
      // Return the string
      return unescape ( queryString.substring ( begin, end ) );
   }
   // Return "null" if no parameter has been found
   return "null";
   }
}
```