# How to get http get parameter in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

given the following data.xml file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="report.xsl"?>

<xml />
```

I would like to get the following output when accessing http:\\localhost\data.xml?id=my_id:

> My id is: **my_id**

I have the following report.xsl but it does not work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<body>
My id is:
<xsl:param name="id"/>
<xsl:if test="$id=(value)">
<xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
</body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Mozillla long time ago introduced some `<?xslt-param name="id" select="'my_id'"?>` for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/PI_Parameters. I don't know whether they still support it or whether other browser vendors have also implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is not possible to pass parameters from the xml URL to the XSL:
[Is it possible to pass a parameter to XSLT through a URL when using a browser to transform XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-parameter-to-xslt-through-a-url-when-using-a-browser-to)